# Python Bokeh Plot not displaying vertical area stack

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am attempting to create a simple normalized, stacked graph of how coronavirus clades are changing over time.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ad0T.png) is the graph reproduced in Excel.

I have already got my data into what I believe is the correct format.  The first column is dates, and the rest are clades, with values being the number of that clade found on that date.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGuMf.png) is a snapshot of the dataframe (called `cot_pvt`).

I use the following code to set up the figure/plot:

```
        source = ColumnDataSource(cot_pvt)

        output_file(self.base_path + "test.html")

        # create a new plot with a title and axis labels
        p = figure(
            title="Clades over time",
            x_axis_label='Time',
            x_axis_type='datetime',
            y_axis_label='Percent dominance',
            sizing_mode='stretch_width'
        )

        stackers = cot_pvt.columns.tolist()
        stackers.remove('doc')
        #add a line renderer with legend and line thickness to the plot
        p.varea_stack(
            stackers=stackers,
            x='doc',
            color=inferno(len(stackers)),
            source=source
        )

        p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'

        # show the results
        show(p)
```

When I run this code, I always end up with an [empty glyph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQW5.png).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `stackers=cot_pvt.columns` include the `doc` column? If so, that is a mistake. Stackers should be the columns of `y` values that you want to stack, and `doc` contains your x-coordinates. Are those dates parsed to real datetimes? Or are they just string categories? If the former you need to specify a datetime axis. If the latter, you need to supply the categorical factors for the range.

Comment: Good catch! I originally had included the `doc` column in the `cot_pvt.column` list.  I have since removed it.  I also updated the `figure()` call to include `x_axis_type=datetime`, and confirmed that the `doc` column was a datetime type, but the chart is still empty after the `show()` call.  My new code can be seen reflected in the edited (original) question.  I don't know if it's relevant, but I was able to produce the line graph in the tutorial of the bokeh docs, so I have had success in producing the graphs before.

Comment: @bigreddot I kept playing with the data and got the plot to show, but it is not normalized.  How can I set the plot so that the stacked graph goes from 0-100% instead of count?

Comment: You'll need to pre-compute normalized (percentage) values to stack yourself, Bokeh does not do any processing on the values you pass. It might also be possible to use a `CustomJSTransform` but I am not 100% that would work with a stacked glyph, also seems like overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bigreddot, If you post an answer I'll mark it as the correct one!